# Why can't if get the correct tid when using omp #pragma omp for schedule(dynamic)?

Tags: c++, openmp

```
#pragma omp parallel private(nthreads, tid)                                                                                                                                                               
{                                                                                 

tid = omp_get_thread_num();                                                                                                                                                                             
printf("Hello World from thread = %d\n", tid);                                                                                                                                                          

/* Only master thread does this */                                                                                                                                                                      
if (tid == 0)                                                                                                                                                                                           
  {                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();                                                                                                                                                                   
    printf("Number of threads = %d\n", nthreads);                                                                                                                                                       
   }                                                                                                                                                                                                    

#pragma omp barrier                                                                                                                                                                                      

#pragma omp for schedule(dynamic)                                                                                                                                                                         
  for(int n=0; n<10; ++n){                                                                                                                                                                               
 printf(" %d", n);                                                                                                                                                                                      
 printf(" %d", tid);                                                                                                                                                                                    
 }                                                                                                                                                                                                      


printf("\n");                                                                                                                                                                                           
}
```

Why when I print the tid with schedule(dynamic) I always get 0, while when using schedule(static) I see each tid print (0-9).  If I was truly concerned what that thread was doing what, I would probably not be using dynamic but I am just curious.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you try commenting barrier line?

Comment: It would help if you'd tell us how many threads you have and what compiler you use. Also, console I/O from different threads might get mixed up. How do you distinguish which `printf` output comes from which thread?